# RoboSpice cache on memory difference object types

Tags: android, robospice

Have a look at [LruCacheObjectPersister.java](https://github.com/octo-online/robospice/blob/release/robospice-cache-parent/robospice-cache/src/main/java/com/octo/android/robospice/persistence/memory/LruCacheObjectPersister.java), this is an in-memory object persister, based on the Android LRUCache. I want to extend this base class to cache any pojos class beside String or bitmap in memory. My goal is execute many kinds of requests in memory and get the result in cache, it look like this:

```
  class Request1 extends SpiceRequest<Book>{}
  class Request2 extends SpiceRequest<Category>{}

  getSpiceManager().execute(new Request1(), CACHE_KEY, 5 * DurationInMillis.ONE_MINUTE, new RequestListener<Book>(){}); 

  getSpiceManager().execute(new Request2(), CACHE_KEY, 5 * DurationInMillis.ONE_MINUTE, new RequestListener<Category>(){});
```

My problem is how to tell the cache manager should support these type in spice service like this:

```
  @Override
public CacheManager createCacheManager(Application application) {
    CacheManager cacheManager = new CacheManager();

    // I want to store any types instead of bitmap
    LruCacheBitmapObjectPersister lruCacheBitmapObjectPersister = new LruCacheBitmapObjectPersister(inFileBitmapObjectPersister, 1024*1024);
    cacheManager.addPersister(inFileBitmapObjectPersister);

    return cacheManager;
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a custom LruCacheXXXXObjectPersister and register it in a custom service. Follow how things are done with bitmaps, and keep the same mechanism for your own POJOs.

Comment: So if I have 100 difference requests for each pojo, I have to create 100 Persister? What I want is all-in-one Persister that works for all of them.

Comment: That's what you get with the basic persisters, but on disk, using JSON for disk caching (for instance, which is quite easy if you got JSON network format). But to persist Pojo in Lru is more difficult, you can get something generic, but you would then need to define a rule that will let you compute the size of each item in RAM. And I really believe that this point is difficult.

Comment: Are you really sure that disk based caching is not efficient enough ? I never had such a case.

Comment: Of course I can do disk cache, but I want my result should be ready in ram, it's cleared whenever I want, and I don't want to take care the cache files. Seem my problem is dealing with generic type to make it accept any types

Comment: It could be achieved I think. Don't forget that persisters are stored in order by the cache manager. First you could register a few very specific object persisters for specific types like bitmap. Then, if you register another persister or factory that claims to deal with everything, it will be responsible for serializing the rest of the types. The biggest challenge for a RAM Lru Cache in that case is to evaluate the size of each Pojo, of different types in RAM. I wouldn't know how to get that size programmatically, but you can estimate it "manually", by decomposing the class in primitives.